# Ubuntu 14.04 In uefi mode

Tags: uefi

I have read that Ubuntu 14.04 can be booted and Installed In Uefi (secure boot mode)
as I don't have a Legacy boot on my Asus Notebook I have tired to boot it this way and
it always go's back to windows  Can someone help am brand new or will as soon as I get some help.

Comment: What model? Some Bay Trail 32 bit models may not easily tall. https://neosmart.net/wiki/disabling-secure-boot/. Another Asus, may be similar, but do not install in legacy mode. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2169462 Also:

Answer (score 0):

Try to **create** bootable **usb** drive with **[Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/usb-creator-gtk/)** (not sure if it works but worked for me before).

Don't try to install it before reading more about UEFI bios and the GPT partition system.

PS: If you **mess up** your boot loader don't panic and **try to boot with >>>[Super Grub](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/)<<<**
    
    Once you have booted successfully with Super Grub try **>>>[Boot-Repair](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/bootrepair.html)<<<**